# ¿Cómo hacer una lista de listas apartir de una lista segun una condición dada por un elemento de la lista padre?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo que separar en listas archivos que contengan el mismo nombre pero con diferentes extensiones asu vez esa listas deben estar contenidas en una lista.

He desarrollado esto con bucles for pero no se si hay una forma más eficiente y si es posible usar menos lineas de código. comparto mi código

```
lst = ['Iris.pdf', 'Orchids.csv', 'Rose.csv', 'Iris.txt', 'Lavender.csv',  
   'Lily.csv','Iris.csv', 'Carnations.csv','Rose.txt','Rouse.pdf']

lista_inter = []
lista_final = []
for e in lst:
    lista_inter.append(e.split(".")[0])

lista_inter = list(set(lista_inter))

print("lista inicial ", lst)
print("lista_intermedia ", lista_inter)


for a in lista_inter:
    temporal_list = []
    for b in lst:
        
        if a in b:
            temporal_list.append(b)
    lista_final.append(temporal_list)
    print("lista final", lista_final)
```

Nota: La lista intermedia esta comprendida por los elementos de la lista lst no repetidos y sin extensión.

Esto me da el resultado requerido pero como menciono busco saber si puede hacer de una manera mejor, gracias de antemano.

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Para estos casos donde hay que contar o seleccionar, lo mejor es usar un diccionario. En este caso, lo natural es un diccionario con el nombre del archivo por llave, y que tenga por valor la lista de archivos de igual nombre y distinta extensión.

Recorremos la lista de nombre. Por cada uno, separamos nombre y extensión y agregamos el nombre completo al diccionario:

```
dicc = {}
for archivo in lst:
    nombre, extension = archivo.split('.')
    if nombre not in dicc:
        dicc[nombre] = []
    dicc[nombre].append(archivo)
```

Con eso solo nos queda recorrer el diccionario para formar la lista final, lo que podemos hacer con una comprensión de listas:

```
lista = [extension for nombre, extension in dicc.items()]
```

#### Demo

```
lst = ['Iris.pdf', 'Orchids.csv', 'Rose.csv', 'Iris.txt', 'Lavender.csv',  
   'Lily.csv','Iris.csv', 'Carnations.csv','Rose.txt','Rouse.pdf']

dicc = {}
for archivo in lst:
    nombre, extension = archivo.split('.')
    if nombre not in dicc:
        dicc[nombre] = []
    dicc[nombre].append(archivo)

print(dicc)
lista = [extension for nombre, extension in dicc.items()]

print(lista)
```

produce:

```
{'Iris': ['Iris.pdf', 'Iris.txt', 'Iris.csv'], 'Orchids': ['Orchids.csv'], 'Rose': ['Rose.csv', 'Rose.txt'], 'Lavender': ['Lavender.csv'], 'Lily': ['Lily.csv'], 'Carnations': ['Carnations.csv'], 'Rouse': ['Rouse.pdf']}
[['Iris.pdf', 'Iris.txt', 'Iris.csv'], ['Orchids.csv'], ['Rose.csv', 'Rose.txt'], ['Lavender.csv'], ['Lily.csv'], ['Carnations.csv'], ['Rouse.pdf']]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es utilizar expresiones regulares

En la función `file_list` primero se obtienen los nombres únicos de los archivos capturándolos con la expresión regular `r"(.*?)\.([^\.]*)$"`,  que permite reconocer nombres de archivo con varias palabras separadas por un espacio con un punto y su extensión obteniendo solamente los que son únicos con una [set comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/set_comprehension.html) para la variable `names` después la función retorna con [list comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html) una lista de listas con archivos del mismo nombre con extensiones distintas

```
import re

lst = ['Iris.pdf', 'Orchids.csv', 'Rose.csv',
       'Iris.txt', 'Lavender.csv', 'Lily.csv',
       'Iris.csv', 'Carnations.csv', 'Rose.txt', 'Rouse.pdf']


def file_list(lista):
    names = {re.search(r"(.*?)\.([^\.]*)$", filename)[1] for filename in lista}
    return [re.findall(rf"{name}\.\w+", " ".join(lst)) for name in names]


print(file_list(lst))
```

Resultado

`[['Lily.csv'], ['Rouse.pdf'], ['Lavender.csv'], ['Rose.csv', 'Rose.txt'], ['Iris.pdf', 'Iris.txt', 'Iris.csv'], ['Carnations.csv'], ['Orchids.csv']]`

Aqui está el código en [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PpRp4unvwrsZ7PX540OaP7rHMmxripcn?usp=sharing)

Edit: en esta versión la expresión regular `r"(.*?)\.([^\.]*)$"` que permite reconocer nombres con múltiples espacios y puntos como sugirió @candidmoe

Comment: Tu expresion regular saltaria, por ejemplo, los archivos cuyo nombre tiene un espacio.

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta para incluir ese caso y también para archivos con nombre de hasta 5 palabras separadas por un espacio.

Comment: La expresión regular `(.*?)\.([^\.]*)$` reconoce nombres con múltiples espacios y puntos.

Comment: Si @CandidMoe, es mucho mejor esa expresión, que puede usarse porque en `names ` se ocupa de cada elemento de la lista, yo erróneamente estaba pensando capturar los nombres de una cadena de texto, no por elemento como lo hace la comprensión de conjunto.